# Substitute WP7 splash screen image at runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7, splash-screen

I know that most likely this is impossible due to the resource structure of XAP, but I still should as, just to be clear:

In order to set a splash screen in Windows Phone application, one needs to put it in the project's root in .jpg. This will show a static image while application is initializing.

I want to be able to show always different splash screen image, when user opens my application.

If I do this using a custom splash screen technique (just a page with a background worker), I will arrive at a slow loading splash screen. It is basically cheating the user and the performance, if I am not mistaking.

Is it possible to substitute a SplashScreenImage.jpg in the XAP package at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot modify anything that has been included in the XAP at runtime. So, whilst you can read files, you can't edit them or rename them via your code. The only solution I can think of is what you've suggested and have a fake splash screen which is actually a simple, quick loading page. This page could load the image from isolated storage and can change each time.